# Snippet Syncing not working

Tags: javascript, snippets, snippet-sync

I am building an html5 theme into expression engine. The theme came with a lot of JS that wasnt needed and it slows the pages down. When initially building the theme into expression engine i broke the site up into snippets and templates as expected. I have now cleaned up the code and removed all unnecessary js. The issue is that my html-header with the JS links in it wont sync. The snippet is still showing the old code and not the updated version. ANy ideas?

Comment: How did you edited your snippet? Directly in CP or you are using Mountee or some addon?

Comment: check the permissions on the folder/file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that in snippet sync it was looking for {snippet:global_sidebar}  - rather than {sn:global_sidebar}

Answer (score 0):

Check that the file path matches snippet sync's file path.

```
$config[‘snippet_file_basepath’] = ‘/my/path/’;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to throw this out there in case some one else ran into it, but I had a similar issue and for some reason snippets were being created with incorrect permissions.  Making changes in the text editor appeared to be working correctly, while loading the same snippet via the EE edit panel `Design -> Templates -> snippets -> snippet name` still showed the old code for that snippet.  Updating permissions solved this issue.